# material table pagination not when i switch between the form and and table which are in same html page

Tags: pagination, angular-material-table

When i switch between the form and table, the material table pagination gets disabled. No error is thrown and when i refresh its enable. I tried my best. Please help me out to solve this problem

code for material table ts code

```js
displayedColumns: string[] = ['Receptionist', 'Slot', 'Status', 'Timing', 'Action'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  
  
  this.authService.getReceptionistList(data).subscribe((recep) => {
      if (recep.status) {
        this.receptionLists = recep.receptionist;
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.receptionLists).length; i++) {
          this.recepList.push(this.receptionLists[i]);
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.recepList);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          this.filteredDataLength = this.dataSource.filteredData.length;
        }
      }
    });
    
   
     applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

I didn't mention the code for the table coz its quite big

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
                  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Receptionist">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Receptionist </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Slot">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Slot</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">shift1 </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.status == 1 ? 'active': 'inactive'}} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Timing">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Timing </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.timings[0]['monday']['shift1'].start_time}} : {{row.timings[0]['monday']['shift1'].end_time}} </td>
<!--                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">12:00 PM - 14:00 PM</td>-->
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row ">
                        <div class="btn btn-group">
                          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="editDeskUserClick(row.user_id)"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt pointer"></i></button>
                          <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="deleteDeskUser(row.user_id)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[7, 14, 21, 100]" showFirstLastButtons ></mat-paginator>
                </div>
```